# Firebase React Native Expo login error with google

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, expo

Error message : `(0, _auth.signInWithRedirect) is not a function. (In '(0, _auth.signInWithRedirect)(_firebaseConfig.authentication, _firebaseConfig.provider)', '(0, _auth.signInWithRedirect)' is undefined)`

---

Even though I did everything right, it gives this error. It works on the web but I get this error on my android phone.

**My login function :**

```
const signInWithGoogle = async () => {
    try {
        const result = await signInWithRedirect(authentication, provider);
        const user = result.user;
        console.log(user)
    }
    catch (error) {
        const errorMessage = error.message;
        console.log(errorMessage)
    };
}
```

Comment: Can you share complete code so we can see how you're importing signInWithRedirect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`signInWithRedirect` does not work in React Native. From Firebase [blog](https://firebase.blog/posts/2016/07/firebase-react-native) -

> Headful" auth methods such as signInWithPopup(), signInWithRedirect(),
> linkWithPopup(), and linkWithRedirect() do not work in React Native
> (or Cordova, for that matter). You can still sign in or link with a
> federated provider by using signInWithCredential() with an OAuth token
> from your provider of choice.

You can use `signInWithCredential` or use [React Native Firebase](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase)